# How to use FFMpeg -timestamp syntax

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

[image]

Hi, All!

```
     ffMpeg -timstamp
```

option works likes upper image?
07:21:54 07/07/05 white text in black box container.

in ubuntu 12.04
typed the excute like this.

```
     ffmpeg -y -f video4linux2 -s vga -r 30 -fs 1M -i /dev/video0 -timestamp now -copyts ./USB1_Test_vga.mp4
```

but it doesn't work.

is there any other option for display video recorded time?

Comment: The `ffmpeg -timestamp` option takes a date, which it stores in the output file.  It is not related to the timecode and does not cause any text to be rendered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There used to be a drawtext filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/DroidSans.ttf: timecode='09\:57\:00\:00': r=25: \
x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000000@1" -an -y out.mp4
```

See here: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FilteringGuide

I believe you can replace the exact time code with a sprintf like syntax.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='%{localtime\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

See here:
http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/